# Enable macros with pop-up bar/dialog box rather than "File" menu button

Tags: excel, vba

It appears that MS Excel opens macro-enabled workbooks in one of three ways:

1. A pop-up bar that includes an "Enable macros" button;
2. A pop-up dialog box that includes an "Enable macros" button; or
3. No pop-up at all with a hidden "Enable Content" button maddeningly hidden within the "File" menu under the "Info" section.

Is there any way to force Excel to use a pop-up notification that always allows the user to automatically enable macros with the convenient click of a button? This is especially critical given that I have macros that run automatically when the workbook opens. However, under the third option mentioned above, the user would never know to click the "Enable Content" button in the File>Info menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you cannot influence this behavior in any way with your Excel file because it is part of the VBA security.

1. The yellow bar "*SECURITY WARNING Macros have been disabled.*" with the "*Enable Content*" button is the default way how Excel tells you that macros are disabled.
2. The pop-up dialog box comes up **only** if the Visual Basic Editor is also open while you open a workbook.
3. "File" › "Info" option always works **additionally** to (1) and (2) so at least (1) or (2) should trigger too. If nothing pops up then the user probably chose one of these security settings:

   - "*Disable all macros without notification*" or
   - "*Disable all macros except digitally signed macros*" and your macro isn't signed

For more info see: [How To Enable Macros In Excel: Step-By-Step Guide To Dealing With 3 Common Scenarios](https://powerspreadsheets.com/how-to-enable-macros-excel/)

A good alternative would be to digitally sign your code with a officially trusted certificate so users would not need to activate macros. They would only once need to trust your certificate on each computer. (If it is a company environment use GPO to trust the certificate on any company computers automatically).